# PDF Searching/Http Syncing on iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf

I have two requirements with handling PDFs on an iPad, but I can't seem to find one app that will solve the problem. I was hoping the iOS 4.2 update would address this, but it doesn't.

Here are my requirements:

1. I need to be able to search for words in a PDF.
2. I need to have this PDF sync to a HTTP url. That is to say, I want my PDF on my iPad to be the exact same (the latest revision) of my PDF on my HTTP server.

The ideal solution would be able to just use Safari and open up the PDF via Safari. However, with Safari, I can't search for text within a PDF.

Any thoughts on how I can solve my problem? Any apps out there that will do this? iBooks or Goodreader don't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[DropBox](http://dropbox.com) and [iAnnotate](http://www.ajidev.com/iannotate/), and since iAnnotate supports DropBox you really only work with one program as requested.